# Matrix calculus derivative form to canonical differential form

Tags: matrix-calculus, differential, canonical-transformation

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus under **Conversion from differential to derivative form** we can see the equivalence:

[image]

How can this be proven ?

Comment: It's easier to see if write the differential in terms of the trace/Frobenius product $$\eqalign{dy&={\rm tr}(A\,dX)=A^T:dX\cr\frac{\partial y}{\partial X}&=A^T}$$Then depending on your preferred layout convention, the result is either $A^T$ or $A$.

Comment: Ok, but why $\eqalign{dy&={\rm tr}(A\,dX)}$ ?

Comment: Given the function $\,y={\rm tr}(AX)=A^T:X,\,$ this is how you'd write the differential and gradient.